# Clone View as attachment

Tags: views

I am using [Views-7.x-3](https://drupal.org/project/views). I have a master view and many content panes views under it. Recently I have a requirement in which I have to create attachment for one of the content pane view. When I clicked on adding an attachment it cloned the all the formats, fields, filter criteria etc from the master display, which I do not want as I want to have same copy of the my content pane view as an attachment which has many addition fields, context filter as well.

My query: Is there any way to clone desired view as attachment rather re-creating same fields again?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to clone a View Display (in this case an attachment). For example:

1. Go to **admin/structure/views/view/frontpage** on your Drupal site
2. Select the 'Feed' Display under **Displays**
3. Under 'Feed details', notice the 'Display name' field, look all the way to the right of here and you'll notice a 'view Feed' drop down menu, click the 'down' icon
4. Then click 'clone Feed'

That will cone that particular display, click 'Save' when you're ready to save the changes. For your attachment, follow the steps above and replace the steps with your view, and the name of your attachment.

Comment: I do not want to clone attachment view, but the main view (not master but the other view in my case content pane). For example I want all the fields of front-page in attachment, but the condition is the frontpage has addition fields not as same as the master.

Comment: A content pane is also referred to as a 'Display' in a view. You can clone content panes using the method described above.

Comment: If I clone a content pane can I make that content pane as attachment?

Comment: It technically will not be an attachment, but if you use Panels, you can easily 'attach' it to wherever you need.